# Design or pattern for handling background consumer/producer tasks

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

### Background:

I have a 3D engine implemented using LWJGL aimed largely at rendering a large 'world' - terrain, vegetation, animated creatures, weather, day/night cycle, etc.  The engine manages the resources that are required for rendering such as the various textures, meshes, models, etc.

As the player navigates this world the engine caches the various types of data discarding/releasing resources that are no longer required and loading/caching newly required data on demand.  This is handled by a set of background threads that perform I/O tasks (loading images, loading a new terrain 'chunk', building a model mesh, etc) and a queue of tasks to be executed on the OpenGL context (allocating a new texture, uploading data to a VBO, deleting a texture, etc).

### Current design:

This all works nicely with the exception of tasks that have dependencies.  I'll illustrate with an example - let's say the engine needs to apply a new texture to an object in the scene.

#### This consists of the following steps:

- load the texture image from the file system (I/O background task)
- allocate a texture on the GPU (OpenGL context task)
- upload the image to the texture (OpengL)
- attach the texture to the material for the object (OpenGL, not really but avoids rendering issues)

#### There are a few problems to resolve here:

1. Ideally I want these steps (or tasks) to be atomic and re-usable, for example the engine needs to load images for several other parts of the system - the code is exactly the same and therefore can (and should) be encapsulated and re-used.
2. Some of this can be run in parallel (e.g. load image and allocate
   texture), some of it must be sequential, e.g. cannot upload the
   image until we have loaded it and allocated the texture.
3. Some of the steps have 'resource dependencies' on previous steps, e.g. in
   particular the upload step requires the allocated texture ID and the
   image.

The first two turn out to be relatively straight-forward, it's the last one is what I am struggling with - I cannot seem to come up with a decent design that allows re-usable and relatively atomic tasks to be linked together when there are inter-task dependencies.

#### Some pseudo-code:

```
interface Task implements Runnable {
    TaskQueue getQueue();
}

// Generic load-an-image task
class LoadImageTask implements Task {
    private final String path;
    private BufferedImage image;

    public LoadImageTask( String path ) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    TaskQueue getQueue() { return TaskQueue.BACKGROUND; }

    public void run() {
        // load the image from the given location
    }
}

// Uploads an image to a given texture
class UploadTextureTask implements Task {
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Texture texture;

    ...

    TaskQueue getQueue() { return TaskQueue.RENDER_THREAD; }

    public void run() {
        texture.buffer( image );
    }
}

// Example task manager for the scenario outlined above
class Example extends TaskManager {
    ...

    // Load the texture image
    final LoadImageTask loadImage = new LoadImageTask( ... );
    add( loadImage );

    // Allocate a texture
    final AllocateTextureTask allocate = ...
    add( allocate );

    // Upload texture image
    final UploadTextureTask upload = ...
    add( upload, loadImage, allocate );
}
```

The `add` method in `TaskManager` registers a task on the relevant queue in the background.  The manager gets notified when each task is completed.  When all current tasks are finished (`loadImage` and `allocate` in this case) the manager starts the next task(s) in the sequence.

Note that the final `add` call for the `upload` task tells the manager that it has dependencies on the `load` and `allocate` tasks.

### The problem:

This issue is to how are 'resources' that are returned by 'producer' tasks (e.g. the `LoadImageTask`) passed to the 'consumer' tasks (e.g. `UploadTextureTask`) when those classes are not coupled in any way?

One (rubbish) way would be to have some custom code that calls `loadImage.getImage()` when that task completes and pass it up the 'chain' using `uploadTask.setImage()`, but this pretty much makes the whole approach pointless if one has to write roughly the same task-management code for each use-case.

I have tried defining *consumer* and *producer* interfaces with generic getter/setter methods and linking dependant tasks that have the correctly matching data type, but this approach breaks down if a task consumes more than one resource (as the upload task does above).

I also considered using `Future` and `Callable` (the background task queue uses an `Executor` thread pool anyway) but they are really orientated towards blocking an entire thread rather than resource management per-se.  The number of tasks in this system can be in the thousands, most of which are pending tasks that are currently running or are themselves queued.  Blocking tasks that have not yet even been started seems pretty pointless.  Also the only way (?) to know when a future is completed is by calling `isDone` which implies another layer of complexity to poll finished tasks.

I have researched this problem here and on OpenGL developer and gaming sites but haven't come across any good designs - they either seem to just consist of cut-and-paste code or some sort of shared state (usually a map) with lots of nasty casting everywhere.  Maybe I am not searching for the correct terms?  Or maybe my whole approach is rubbish?

Has anyone implemented or come across anything similar?  Any suggestions, criticisms, pointers are welcome.  (And apologies for the wall-o-text)

Comment: Have you considered using javas Future class. It represents a future result that is computed asynchronously. I.e. Another thread So in your example step 3 could take two future objects in the constructor, that each compute its dependencies. It can call Future.get on these, which will block until each dependency has a result, and will then proceed

Comment: I had considered `Future` but discounted it because it blocks a *thread* rather than a *task*.  The number of tasks at any one time can number in the thousands, most of which are pending on tasks being executed or queued - threads (however cheap) seemed to be overkill in this case.  However I'll take another look at `Future`, maybe I can borrow some of the concept if not the actual implementation.

Comment: Scala has the ability to compose its future objects, so you only ever need to block when you need to use the finished result. It has good interop with java, so that may help reduce the complexity of the solution.

Comment: Conceptual approach makes a simple functional problem obviously complex, I can't see any difficulty in synchronizing such tasks, or I'm missing something...

Comment: @j-p When you say you can't see any difficulty in 'synchronizing' such tasks what approach are you referring to?  Maybe use the `upload` task scenario I tried to describe as an exemplar?

Comment: @stridecolossus: and what alternative scenario for uploading have you got? Queuing available resources in ram for the gpu to process is quite straightforward (at first glance), uploading with pbo is maybe a case to study, but that will not affect your task manager i think.

Comment: @stridecolossus: Is it locking concern? The solution coming to my mind is a shared fifo with interprocess locking function. I use some pipe in a low level multithreded gui lib, I still can't understand what's blocking you...

Comment: Since we are talking OpenGL here, I think "allocated texture" might be a misuse of the terminology. To me, that implies allocating the actual ***storage*** for a texture. What you seem to be implying by "allocate a texture" is the generation of a unique name. This might sound like nitpicking, but something like `glTexImage2D (...)` actually does ***both*** storage allocation and image uploading in a single operation. To break that operation into its component parts, you would have to use `glTexStorage2D (...)` and `glTexSubImage2D (...)`... which makes bullet point ***(2)*** kind of awkward.

Comment: @andon - Good point, I was referring to allocating the texture ID using `glGenTextures`, I'll try and come up with a better name.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the new goodies in Java 8 appear to handle exactly this sort of problem, e.g. `CompletableFuture`, which integrates nicely with the existing design described above using `Executor`s, `Runnable` tasks, etc.